# Definition of an algebraic set being "defined over $k$" in terms of tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field, $I$ a radical ideal, and $k$ a subfield of $\Omega$.  If $I = \mathcal I(A)$ for some closed set $A \subseteq \Omega^n$, then $I_k := I \cap k[X_1, ... , X_n]$ is an ideal of $k[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  We say that $A$ is **defined** over $k$ if the homomorphism of $\Omega$-modules: $$I_k \otimes_k \Omega \rightarrow I$$ defined on generators by $f(X) \otimes c \mapsto cf(x)$ is an isomorphism.  When $A$ is not necessarily defined over $k$, what is the nature of the homomorphism I just mentioned?  Is it injective?  Also, is $k$ allowed to be a subring (even a subring without $1$) of $\Omega$ rather than a subfield?  What is the significance of this definition?

Answer (score 2):

Being defined over $k$ basically means that you can write down generators for the ideal with coefficients in $k$.

To see how this is encoded by the definition you've given, take $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$, $k = \mathbb{R}$, $n = 1$, and
$$I = (x-i) < \mathbb{C}[x].$$
Of course any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ divisible by $x-i$ is also divisible by $x+i$, and hence by $(x+i)(x-i) = x^2 + 1$.  So
$$I_\mathbb{R} = (x-i) \cap \mathbb{R}[x] = (x^2+1) < \mathbb{R}[x].$$
When we try to take $I_\mathbb{R}$ back to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$, of course, we get
$$I_\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \mapsto (x^2+1) \subsetneq (x-i)$$
That is, since we couldn't write down generators for $I$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, when we restricted it to $\mathbb{R}[x]$ we "lost part of the ideal," which remained lost when we brought it back to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$.
This ideal *is* defined over $\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, if you'd taken $J = (x-7) < \mathbb{C}[x]$, then you'd get $$J_\mathbb{R} = (x-7) < \mathbb{R}[x],$$
 and so
$$J_\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \mapsto (x-7) = (x-7);$$
this ideal *is* defined over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see, so for the example you gave with $I = (X - i)$, the tensor product $I_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ injects into the ideal $\mathbb{C}[X](X - i)$.  In general though, is the $k$-module homomorphism $I_k \otimes_k \Omega \rightarrow I$ injective?

Comment: Yes, because $\Omega$ is flat over $k$.